# Android Chrome SharedWorker issues

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, shared-worker

Android Chrome thows an exception at "new SharedWorker()". It prints that SharedWorker is undefined, but the same code perfectly works at desktop Chrome. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Now it's clear. SharedWorkers are not supported by Android Chrome: https://caniuse.com/#search=SharedWorker